# Writing test cases using CodeIgniter

Tags: unit-testing, codeigniter, phpunit

How can I write a test case for Controller/Model using CodeIgniter? Can anyone please provide a reference link if possible. I am new to test cases using CodeIgniter.

I have checked on CI site but didn't find how we implement test cases in CI. Also i have search on Google for it but didn't get any appropriate guide for same.

Comment: Can't you just write it? Or do I seem to be missing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider fooStack: http://www.foostack.com/foostack/
I've been using it for a while, and it works. It seems as it's only been tested with version 1.7.2

Comment: Thanks, But can you please let me know if there is any sample test case written to test the controller and models.